# Can we execute unix command inside %install section?

Tags: linux, sybase, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have created an rpm without source using the binary file I had been provided. In a nutshell, I am trying to automate a silent install of `sybase` client via an rpm. However I need help whether we can put the following silent install command in the `%install` section of the spec file -

```
setup.bin –f <responseFileName> -i silent -DAGREE_TO_SYBASE_LICENSE=true -DRUN_SILENT=true
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: %install section is executed when you build an rpm not when you install it. what result, exactly do you try to achieve with this command?

Comment: I have put the above code in %post section as I dont want it executed whilst building the rpm but rather I would like the rpm to run the setup.bin when it is installed on the linux server. Hopefully this will the right start ? I am about to try this out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a script to be executed when you install a package, it must be put in the `%post` section. According to your comment, this is what you did.

The problem is that if you run the install script that way, rpm will not be able to track the installed files. It will not know that those files belong to the package, will not remove them when you uninstall the rpm, will not handle updates properly, etc. You will have a broken rpm.

If you can't build a proper rpm, just use a simple install script that does what you want.

Comment: thank you for the guidance. We needed to package it as an rpm for a reason otherwise I am happy to use the command as mentioned in my question. But I do understand what you are trying to say, however I achieved the outcome with as less damage as possible.